# Output hidden state of LSTM RNN in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to change the model used in the [lstm-text-generation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/lstm-text-generation) example of the official [tfjs-examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples) to output its hidden state. To do this, I first changed the usage of `tf.sequential` to `tf.model` in `createModel` of `model.js`.

Original line 37 - 47 of file [`model.js`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/lstm-text-generation/model.js#L37)

```
// (...)
const model = tf.sequential();
for (let i = 0; i < lstmLayerSizes.length; ++i) {
  const lstmLayerSize = lstmLayerSizes[i];
  model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
    units: lstmLayerSize,
    returnSequences: i < lstmLayerSizes.length - 1,
    inputShape: i === 0 ? [sampleLen, charSetSize] : undefined
  }));
}
model.add(
  tf.layers.dense({units: charSetSize, activation: 'softmax'}));
// (...)
```

Customized lines of same file `model.js`.

```
// (...)
// This replaces `inputShape` of the first LSTM layer
const inputs = tf.input({ shape: [sampleLen, charSetSize] });

let outputs = inputs;
for (let i = 0; i < lstmLayerSizes.length; ++i) {
  const lstmLayerSize = lstmLayerSizes[i];
  const layer = tf.layers.lstm({
    units: lstmLayerSize,
    returnSequences: i < lstmLayerSizes.length - 1,
  });

  outputs = layer.apply(outputs);
}

outputs = tf.layers
  .dense({ units: charSetSize, activation: 'softmax' })
  .apply(outputs);

const model = tf.model({ inputs, outputs });
// (...)
```

As far as I understood, I would need to add `returnState: true` to the lstm layer options to achieve my goal.

```
// (...)
// Inside of the for loop
const layer = tf.layers.lstm({
  units: lstmLayerSize,
  returnState: true, // <-- Here
  returnSequences: i < lstmLayerSizes.length - 1,
});
// (...)
```

However, this does not work with the last model layer as it expects only one input tensor, but setting `returnState` to `true` changes the lstm layers to output 3 tensors `[output, hiddenState, cellState]`.

I'm not sure how to achieve my goal of keeping the dense layer for the `softmax` `activation` and still printing the hidden state.

Another thing which isn't clear to me, is that I'd probably also need to adjust the outputs of the `.fit` method, as it [expects target data as second argument `y`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.LayersModel.fit) when training the model.

Any help is greatly appreciated.